# Can't change the permission from 'root' to my user on MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, file-permissions

I am fairly new to the scene and already have permission problems on my mac. I have been trying to install truffle and had  permission issues, because my node_modules folder was owned by root. I somehow managed to change it to my user but now when I am trying to run `truffle version` all it says is *command not found: truffle*

When I put in `ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules` to check the permissions, it says that theres still a folder owned by root:

[image: Permission for root still there]

Now I tried every command that I found with `sudo` and `chown` but nothing really works. I dont even know why - in this folder theres one permisson for my user "nd" and one for "root". Can somebody please help me out here? How can I change the permission from root to my user to have fully access to the directory?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Everything in /usr should be owned by root. What are you actually trying to achieve? What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a few things may be the cause of the issue with this file.

First, a quick refresher on unix file permissions:
Every file has a group and a user it is tied to. Every file also has three sets of permissions, the permissions for the user, permissions for the group, and permissions for everyone else. Permissions just means: is the file readable, is it writable, and is it executable.

In the output of ls, take this example line (with some irrelevant bits left out)

```
drwxr-x--x nd   wheel <filename>
^111222333 user group
```

The spot marked `^` shows that this listing is a directory. Regular files have a dash there. The set of 3 letters labelled 1 are the user permisions. As you can see, `rwx` are all show, which means the user can read from, write to, and execute this file. Meanwhile, members of the group `wheel` are allowed to read and execute, but not write (`r-x`). Finally, all other users are allowed only to execute.

A few notes:
1.) The entry that appears to be owned by root is `..`, which is shorthand for the parent directory. This means that even if `..` is owned by root, it doesn't necessarily change who owns the files within.

2.) Similar to the first note, did you add `-R` when you were changing the file owners? Otherwise, the changes would not have applied to any sub-directories.

There isn't enough information in your question to fully answer it. The directory structure, as well as your path, would be helpful to figuring it out. However, based on what I do know, I have 3 guesses as to the possible cause.

Possible explanation 1: you only changed the owner of the parent folder, not the file. Make sure you have the `x` permission for the actual file.

Possible explanation 2: you own the file, but it is not marked as executable. Even for files you own, if they are not flagged as executable, you are not able to run them as commands. Use `chmod +x filename` to make a file executable.

Possible explanation 3: The path isn't in your path. Every command-line environment has a special variable called the `PATH`. (run `echo $PATH` to see yours). It is a list of folders on your computer. Whenever you run a command, your shell checks if it can find the program you requested to run in any of the folders listed on your path. If it can't, you get the `(command) not found`. There are guides online for how to modify your path, but you should make sure that the folder containing truffle is somewhere on that list.